# Feature Selection, Outlier Removal, Target Transformer for Dask-ML pipelines

Tags: dask, feature-selection, dask-distributed, rapids, dask-ml

While FS, OR, TT have well-established components in "classic" scikit-learn pipelines, documentation of dask-ml and RAPIDS totally omits them.

**What are the best practices to implement Feature Selection, Outlier Removal, Target Transformer in dask-ml when training on large distributed datasets in production? Are there any existing packages already, covering at least a subset of relevant sklearn functionality and compatible with dask-ml/rapids?**

I wasn't able to find anything and I'm wondering why, in my experience these components can be quite important for modelling. Granted, the Target Transformations I can do manually, and I can kind of get away without Outlier Removal for start, but Feature Selection is an absolute must given how many features I have on a cluster.

Comment: Hi Anatoly, this is a broad question. Do you mind to try toprovide a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi, indeed, it's broad, and I would be happy with a broad answer. I am thinking currently to implement own FS algo based on information theory and mRMR and make it Dask-compatible. Will post results here later (hopefully, within a month).

Comment: I recently built a pipeline in production with Rapids and it's basically the same as scikit-learn. I think it will be great to see a given pipeline in scikit-learn and see how to translate in dask.

Comment: Did you use a feature selection block? Which one worked for you? I searched in rapids documentation as well before posting the question, there was no mention of FS, at all.